# how to override viewWillDisappear in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm Trying to hide the first navigation bar and show all the others, so I used:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

what I need now is to call the super methods: `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` and `super.viewWillDisappear(animated)`, but I don't know where or how, any suggestions?

Comment: You already have the correct code in your question. Just add the appropriate call to `super.view...` inside the corresponding method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code will look like

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: please remove the space after super.

Answer (score 0):

The answer written by @Karun Kumar is correct, but it has a space after super. viewwillappear and viewwilldisapper.

Correct code is

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```